# cfftp : Copy and move file remotely?

Tags: coldfusion

I need to copy files from one folder to the another on the same sftp server. My code currently copies the files locally and reuploads them.

```
<cfftp  
  action  = "open"
  username = "#APPLICATION.intxml.SFTPUSERNAME#"
  password = "#APPLICATION.intxml.SFTPPASSWORD#"
  connection = "sftpcon"
  server  = "#APPLICATION.intxml.SFTPADDRESS#"
  port   = "#APPLICATION.intxml.SFTPPORT#"
  timeout  = "#APPLICATION.pageTimeout#"
  secure  = "#sftp#"/>   

 <cfif cfftp.succeeded>

  <cfftp action = "LISTDIR" stopOnError = "No" name = "ListFiles" directory = "/#sfolder#" connection = "sftpcon"/>


     <cfloop query=getFiles>
      <cfftp  action    = "GETFILE"
        stopOnError  = "Yes"
        name    = "theFile"
        transferMode  = "binary" 
        timeout   = 3600
        retrycount  = 10
        remoteFile  = "#sfolder##name#"
        localFile  = "#dfolder#/#name#"
        failIfExists = "no"
        connection   = "sftpcon">

      <cfftp  action    = "PUTFILE"
        stopOnError  = "Yes"
        name    = "theFile"
        transferMode  = "binary" 
        timeout   = 3600
        retrycount  = 10
        localfile  = "#sfolder##name#"
        remoteFile  = "#dfolder#/#name#"
        failIfExists = "no"
        connection   = "sftpcon">

     </cfloop>

    </cfif>

 <cfftp action = "close"
      connection = "sftpcon"
      stopOnError = "Yes">
```

Is there a better way to do this with coldfusion?

Comment: I searched the Googles about move files in general with FTP (http://www.google.com/search?q=ftp%20move%20files%20on%20remote%20server) and it appears rename may do the job for moving files.

Comment: tried it before I posted the question. need to keep the original files.

Comment: The FTP protocol doesn't support remote copies.  Your download/upload method is about as good as you can get over FTP.

Comment: Thanks Ben & Orangepips. I was hoping someone had a clever workaround.

Comment: i haven't tried it, but could you use action="rename" to (in effect) move the file? I use this with cffile fairly regularly.

Comment: Possible to use a SSH instead? This would let you do it. No CF tags to make it happen, but if the file(s) big enough or bandwidth small enough, will save a lot of time.

Comment: Before going ahead with the CFFTP Rename command, you may want to do some research into how that works.  It may download the file, rename it, upload the new file and delete the old one.

Comment: @op Denied ssh access but they created and scheduled a shell script to do it nightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the [ftp protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) does not provide a way to remotely copy a file into another folder and keep the original. That precludes coldfusion from providing a solution. Moving files on the other hand can be done with a rename. See the other answer and comments on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

With CFFTP you can do a RENAME (check the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7347.html)) which should solve your problem

Comment: This was covered about 12 hours before your answer in question's comments.

Answer (score 0):

Code to show directories of files:

```
    <cfftp
        username=   "username"
        password=   "password"
        port=       "22"
        server=     "hostofyousystem"
        secure=     "yes"
        name=       "ftpconnection"
        action=     "listdir"
        directory=  "/" />

    <cfdump var="#ftpconnection#" />

    <cfoutput query="ftpconnection">
        #path#<br/>
    </cfoutput>
```

Code to get file and save it in our system if file exist then replace:

```
    <cfftp
        username=    "username"
        password=    "password"
        port=        "22"
        server=      "hostofyousystem"
        secure=      "yes"
        action=      "getFile"
        remotefile=  "/myfile.csv"
        localfile=   "D:/web/files/Data/thisfile.csv"
        failIfExists="no" />
```